# How to keep CSS box inside father when the window resize

Tags: css, resize, position

I have read that to make a children box relative to its father , you must set the children position to absolute and the father position to relative.
But , in practice , I'am having some troubles.

I have an example of it , if you want to see it in this link :

[Code Pen link](https://codepen.io/izzypt/pen/poEBZqr)

Basically , what happens is this :

I have set a box relative to its parent 75% to the left , which looks fine when the windows is full size.

```
<body>

<div id = "myspace"> My Space
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <div id = "wallet">Minha Carteira<hr>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <ul style="list-style: none;">     
                <li>Stock 1</li>
                <li>Stock 2</li>
                <li>Stock 3</li>
                <li> Ou adicione mais acções à sua carteira , clicando aqui..</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div id = "calendario">Calendário e Eventos<hr>
        <div class="dropdown-content2">
            <div id ="calendar-box"></div>
        </div>
        <table></table>
    </div>

    <div id = "resumo">Resumo do dia<hr></div>
</div>

</body>
```

```
#myspace
{
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    position : relative;
}

#wallet
{
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin : 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown-content
{
    display : none;
}

li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width : 96%;
}

li:hover
{
    background-color: white;
}

#wallet:hover .dropdown-content
{
    display : block;
    cursor: grab;
}

#calendario
{
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin : 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.dropdown-content2
{
    display : none;

}

li{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width : 96%;
}

#calendario:hover .dropdown-content2
{
    display : block;
    position: relative;
}

#calendar-box
{
    height : 300px;
    width : 300px;
    border : 2px solid black;
    margin : 5px;
    position: relative;
    left : 70%;
}
```

The issue happens when I resize the window this box , goes outside the parent , when it should maintain its position relative to the parent.

I have tried to change the position both of the father and the children between relative and absolute , but still I keep failing.

Some help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Which div are you trying to position?

Comment: @Paulie_D , Hi , I'am trying to always keep div "calendar-box" to the right of the box he is in, regardless of the window size.

#calendar-box
{
    height : 300px;
    width : 300px;
    border : 2px solid black;
    margin : 5px;
    position: relative;
    left : 70%;
}

Comment: then it should have position absolute and **it's** parent relative.

Comment: @Paulie_D you know , the problem is that if I do that , the dropdown stops working when I hover the div father.